# Что плохого в моем коде тестового задания на java?

Tags: java, maven, инспекция-кода, junit

Задача тестового: привести примеры использования ООП
Что подтянуть? Критикуйте пожоще.

Maven проект, 4 класа, unit тесты

> #### Сущности:
>
> - Постоянный конденсатор(Fixed capacitor)
> - Электролитический конденсатор(Polarized capacitor)
> - Перемнный конденсатор(Polarized capacitor)
>
> #### Задача:
>
> - Задав характеристику емкости будушего конденсатора(пикофарады или стетфорды,1п=3с):
>
>   1. получить стоимость производства конденсатора.
>   2. получить количество нужного материала для производства:
>
>      - Постоянного:
>
>        - нужен алюминий
>        - нужна бумага
>      - Электролитичиского:
>
>        - нужен электролит
>        - нужна сталь
>      - Перемнного:
>
>        - нужно железо
>        - нужна пластмаса

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Capacitor> capacitors = new ArrayList<Capacitor>();

        // Random generate capacitors.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int typeCapacitor = random.nextInt(3);

            if(typeCapacitor == 0) {
                Capacitor capacitor = new FixedCapacitor();
                capacitor.setPicofarad(72);
                capacitors.add(capacitor);
            } else if(typeCapacitor == 1) {
                Capacitor capacitor = new PolarizedCapacitor();
                capacitor.setPicofarad(137);
                capacitors.add(capacitor);

            } else {
                Capacitor capacitor = new VariableCapacitor();
                capacitor.setPicofarad(60);
                capacitors.add(capacitor);
            }
        }

        // Calculate price sum each and all products.
        int sumAllProducts = 0;
        for (Capacitor capacitor : capacitors) {
            int priceProduct = capacitor.getPrice();
            sumAllProducts += priceProduct;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Capacitor {
    int picofarad;

    public abstract boolean setPicofarad(int picofarad);
    public abstract boolean setStatfarad(int statfarad);
    public abstract int getPicofarad();
    public abstract int getStatfarad();
    public abstract int getPrice();
}
```

```
public class FixedCapacitor extends Capacitor {
    private final static int MIN_PICOFARAD = 1;
    private final static int MAX_PICOFARAD = 100000;
    private final static int ALUMINIUM_COEFFICIENT = 5;
    private final static int PAPER_COEFFICIENT = 6;

    public int getGramsAluminium() {
        return (picofarad * ALUMINIUM_COEFFICIENT - 7) * 2;
    }
    public int getGramsPaper() {
        return picofarad * PAPER_COEFFICIENT + 7;
    }
    public boolean setPicofarad(int picofarad) {
        if (picofarad >= MIN_PICOFARAD && picofarad <= MAX_PICOFARAD) {
            this.picofarad = picofarad;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean setStatfarad(int statfarad) {
        if ((statfarad >= 3 * MIN_PICOFARAD) && (statfarad <= 3 * MAX_PICOFARAD)) {
            picofarad = 3 * statfarad;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int getPicofarad() {
        return picofarad;
    }
    public int getStatfarad() {
        return picofarad * 3;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return (picofarad + 3) * 23 / 2;
    }
}
```

```
public class PolarizedCapacitor extends Capacitor {
    private final static int MIN_PICOFARAD = 50;
    private final static int MAX_PICOFARAD = 100000;
    private final static int ELECTROLYTE_COEFFICIENT = 22;
    private final static int STEEL_COEFFICIENT = 50;

    public int getMillilitersElectrolyte() {
        return (picofarad + 5) * ELECTROLYTE_COEFFICIENT / 3;
    }
    public int getGramsSteel() {
        return (picofarad + 1) * STEEL_COEFFICIENT / 2;
    }
    public boolean setPicofarad(int picofarad) {
        if (picofarad >= MIN_PICOFARAD && picofarad <= MAX_PICOFARAD) {
            this.picofarad = picofarad;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean setStatfarad(int statfarad) {
        if (statfarad >= 3 * MIN_PICOFARAD && statfarad <= 3 * MAX_PICOFARAD) {
            picofarad = 3 * statfarad;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int getPicofarad() {
        return picofarad;
    }
    public int getStatfarad() {
        return picofarad * 3;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return (picofarad + 5) * 22 / 3;
    }
}
```

```
public class VariableCapacitor extends Capacitor {
    private final static int MIN_PICOFARAD = 100;
    private final static int MAX_PICOFARAD = 100000;
    private final static int PLASTIC_COEFFICIENT = 23;
    private final static int CAST_IRON_COEFFICIENT = 50;

    public int getGramsPlastic() {
        return (picofarad + 5) * PLASTIC_COEFFICIENT / 4;
    }
    public int getGramsCastIron() {
        return (picofarad + 1) * CAST_IRON_COEFFICIENT / 2;
    }
    public boolean setPicofarad(int picofarad) {
        if (picofarad >= MIN_PICOFARAD && picofarad <= MAX_PICOFARAD) {
            this.picofarad = picofarad;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean setStatfarad(int statfarad) {
        if (statfarad >= 3 * MIN_PICOFARAD && statfarad <= 3 * MAX_PICOFARAD) {
            picofarad = 3 * statfarad;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int getPicofarad() {
        return picofarad;
    }
    public int getStatfarad() {
        return picofarad * 3;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return (picofarad + 7) * 24 / 3;
    }
}
```

Часть кода тут исключена, остальное смотрите в репозитории на GitHub.

https://github.com/Sharabaddin/oop-examples

Comment: Как минимум стоило вынести общую логику в абстрактный класс (геттеры/сеттеры/константы). Сеттеры в принципе не должны ничего возвращать. В случае ошибки кидайте исключение подходящего типа. Методы, которые не являются геттерами не стоит называть начиная с `get`. В частности гораздо правильнее будет не `getPrice`, а `calculatePrice`. Это  то, что прям по верхам видно

Comment: Почему все методы публичные, это что попрание устоев ООП!?

Comment: У вас ничего не вынесено. Сейчас ваш абстрактный класс является не болеее чем интерфейсром

Comment: я бы вынес логику вычисления цены конденсатора в отдельный класс. Ваш конденсатор сам умеет вычислять свою стоимость, которая может быть различной в зависимости от внешних факторов, рынка, спроса, предложения итд. А так, ваш подход нарушает SRP

Comment: SRP - протокол парольной аутентификации? немого не понимаю при чем он тут и почему его надо придерживаться в задаче не связаной с аутентификацией?

Comment: под SRP имел ввиду single responsibility principle - принцип единой ответственности. Т.е класс должен делать только что-то одно. В вашем случае, класс конденсатора берет на себя ответственность вычислять свою цену

Comment: @mrBatonec *единственной

Comment: @D-side точно, опечатка. А отредактировать не могу

Comment: @rjhdby и почему закрыли?если существует вот такое описания метки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info

Comment: @FORTRAN Вопрос про код должен содержать код, а не ссылки на него на сторонних источниках. А так ваш вопрос в принципе не полезен никому кроме вас https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @FORTRAN, потому что код должен быть в вопросе. Я всё-таки проголосую за переоткрытие, но правилам этот вопрос не соответствует.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если хотите, чтобы народ проголосовал за переоткрытие, то перенесите релевантный код из проекта на гитхабе в вопрос. Голосовать за переоткрытие вопроса, который не соответствует правилам, всё-таки не следует, даже если очень хочется.

Answer (score 2):

1. По условиям задачи, вам для сущности "Конденсатор" необходимы 3(4) метода.

   - получить стоимость производства конденсатора. `calculateCost()`
   - Задав характеристику емкости будушего конденсатора. 1 или 2 сеттера
   - получить количество нужного материала для производстваю `calculateMaterials()`

У вас же на каждый подкласс по 7 публичных методов.

2. Три ваших типа конденсаторов наследуют от одного абстрактного класса в котором... нет ни одного реализованного метода! Т.е. его можно смело рефакторить в интерфейс, но и тут не все гладко. В этот класс у вас зачем-то вынесены только сеттеры и геттеры емкости (зачем геттеры!?), а где остальные 2 метода, про стоимость и материалы?
3. Сеттеры - это такие методы которые, по феншую, не должны ничего возвращать. Максимум, что может себе позволить сеттер - выбросить исключение в случае неадекватных входных данных.
4. Возвращаясь к абстрактному классу. У вас во всех наследниках присутствуют абсолютно идентичные методы `setPicofarad`, `setStatfarad` (и их геттеры, которые не нужны) которые то и необходимо было реализовать в классе предке.
5. В расчете материалов (который у вас выполнен вообще странно как-то) вы используете константы. В расчете стоимости захардкоженные цифры. Косяк.
6. Много лишнего кода (не говоря о том, что вообще не так надо было делать)

Вот это:

```
public boolean setPicofarad(int picofarad) {
    if (picofarad >= MIN_PICOFARAD && picofarad <= MAX_PICOFARAD) {
        this.picofarad = picofarad;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean setStatfarad(int statfarad) {
    if ((statfarad >= 3 * MIN_PICOFARAD) && (statfarad <= 3 * MAX_PICOFARAD)) {
        picofarad = 3 * statfarad;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Должно как минимум выглядеть как-то так:

```
public boolean setPicofarad(int picofarad) {
    if (picofarad < MIN_PICOFARAD || picofarad > MAX_PICOFARAD) {
        return false;
    }
    this.picofarad = picofarad;
    return true;
}

public boolean setStatfarad(int statfarad){
    return setPicofarad(statfarad * 3);
}
```

Пока хватит

Comment: всё таки напомню что задача стояла продемонстрировать использования ООП. Тем не менее  постараюсь учесть всю критику при переработке.

Comment: Так вот как раз ООП то в вашей реализации почти и нет. Инкапсуляции нет - см. п. 1. Наследования нет см. п 2 и 4, полиморфизма тоже нет, (с 
 натяжкой см. п. 6)

Comment: rjhdby. хех ну я сам напросился, буду разбираться. Я думал это не плохой пример 3 принципов ООП.